# in php error in uploading file to the server

Tags: php, audio

I am using this script to upload file to the server.

```
<?php
$name = $_FILES["file"]['name'];
echo $tmp_name = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];


if (isset($name))
 {
   if (!empty($name))
    {
     $location = 'uploads/';
     if (move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $location.$name))
      {
       echo 'Uploadded';
      }
     else
      {
       echo "there was an error";
      }
     }
   else
  {
   echo 'please choose a file.';
  }
 }


?>
<form action="#" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="file"><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

This script is working well at local host (my own pc). But when i upload this code to online then this code is giving following error.

**500-Internal Server error.

There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it can not be displayed.**

Secondly i also want to echo meta tags of mp3 like genre, artist etc. Thank you.

Comment: Do you have access to the php/http error log? If yes, could you post the corresponding message?

Comment: For the meta tags use [get_meta_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-meta-tags.php).

Comment: Sorry sir, i dont know about php/http error log. I am new in php. and how to aceess it.

Comment: Check the beginning of this page: http://www.sitepoint.com/file-uploads-with-php/. Is the `file_uploads` set `on` and does your server have a defined `upload_tmp_dir`? Check the directory from your php.ini file or just define it before the script (make sure the directory has sufficient permissions). Also if you are using some content management system, allowed upload file types might be limited: try to upload a simple text file or jpg image.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is an error occurring with the PHP script, but the server is throwing a HTTP 500 code instead of showing that error. Try adding `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 'On');` at the beginning of the script.

I can guess the possible error is `undefined index` related.

This is because your PHP script is assuming the `$_FILES` always there, without only expecting it when the form is submitted.

Try updating the script like this:

```
<?php

// turn on error reporting
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); 

// proceed if there is a form post
if (count($_FILES))
{
    $name = $_FILES["file"]['name'];
    echo $tmp_name = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

    if (isset($name)) {
        if (!empty($name)) {
            $location = 'uploads/';
            if (move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $location . $name)) {
                echo 'Uploadded';
            } else {
                echo "there was an error";
            }
        } else {
            echo 'please choose a file.';
        }
    }
}


?>
```

Comment: I add these two lines error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); at begining of the script. But still getting same error. 500-Internal Server error......

Comment: how big a file are you uploading? Have you checked `phpinfo()` to see what's the maximum upload file size limit is? Is the script taking too long to upload (i.e. exceeding the max execution time limit)?

Comment: NO sir, my audio file is just 129 kb. This file is properly uploaded to my localhost (my own pc). But when i upload my script then this script is not uploading file online. and showing error.

Comment: I think there is some problem with server.